# Word equation brackets wrong size

Tags: microsoft-word

So I'm doing a maths project and I'm using Word's equations to write down the actual maths, but when I put brackets around a fraction they're the wrong size.

[image: screenshot]

I don't know why it's doing this as it has worked properly in a different part of the document, but it doesn't seem to want to resize the brackets.

Comment: It would help fi you would tag the version of Word you are using. You might also want to save a document demonstrating the problem on OneDrive or DropBox and post a view link here with your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter the bracket manually, they will appear as shown on your image. However, if you select them on the Equation tab -> Brackets, their sizes will automatically increase based on their contents. See the images below for the differences between the two processes.

**Manually typed brackets**

[image]

**Brackets typed via the Equation tab -> Brackets**

[image]